# React Select with react form hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-forms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDVyL.png)

when I select values he show this error

Comment: Would you post your code?

Comment: Either you are trying to read name somewhere where its not defined or RHF is trying to read name somewhere where its not defined. You will need to share your code to get more help in this case